# wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I am using `devise` as an authentication system and created a scenario.

```
Scenario: Home page have a login page
    When I go to the home page
    And user is not logged in
    Then I should see "Sign In"
```

for step definition

```
When /^user is not logged in$/ do
  signed_in? == false
end
```

i had also added Devise helpers to the cucumber world.

```
World(Devise::Controllers::Helpers)
```

and cucumber is generating this error:

```
And user is not logged in           # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:260
      wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:261:in `/^user is not logged in$/'
      features/manage_home_page.feature:13:in `And user is not logged in'
```

Why is it generating and how to fix it?

### Update

the definition of `signed_in?` method is

```
  # Return true if the given scope is signed in session. If no scope given, return
  # true if any scope is signed in. Does not run authentication hooks.
  def signed_in?(scope=nil)
    [ scope || Devise.mappings.keys ].flatten.any? do |scope| 
      warden.authenticate?(:scope => scope)
    end
  end
```

its defined in Devise and i added that helper to cucumber by writing this code `World(Devise::Controllers::Helpers)` into cucumber's paths.rb file.

Comment: Can you show us the code which is at line 261 of 'web_steps.rb'?

Comment: on line 261 the code is `signed_in? == false`. I also changed the code to `signed_in?.should be(false)`. But it still don't work.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `signed_in?`?  Is it a method, or property?  Something in that step is expecting a parameter which you're not supplying...

Comment: updated the question. i had used signed_in? in my code many times without any parameters. but it is not working with cucumber.

Comment: I think it'll be difficult to diagnose without seeing the full source - is it up on Github, or available somewhere else?

Comment: What source do you want to see? signed_in? is a devise method and devise is on github. All other code is given in the question.

Comment: I meant that if your project, or just the `features` folder was public, then it would be easy to try it and debug, and probably reveal the problem quickly.  

The code you've given looks perfectly fine so most likely the problem is somewhere else, but continuously asking you to post up the odd line of code isn't a realistic way to discover it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Stuck at the same thing

Comment: No at that time I did not found the solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
When /^user is not logged in$/ do
  user_signed_in?.should be_false
end
```

**UPDATED**
I think you need to do something like this

```
When /^user is not logged in$/ do |user| 
  #check here user not logged in
end
```

or 
You could try modifying your feature to

```
Scenario: Home page has a login page
  Given I am on the home page
  And I am not logged in
  Then I should see "Sign In"
```

Then in the steps

```
Given /^user is not logged in$/ do
  visit('users/sign_out')  # this will ensure that the user is not logged in
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems similar to this which turned out to be the test line matching another step definition somewhere else in my code.

It seems unlikely here but do you have anything else which could match to `And user is not logged in` but which requires an argument?

Comment: i checked out again, it do not have any other step which have such kind of step